# SSH Expect script

Tags: ssh, expect

I have this Expect script which called by another script to log Cisco devices. For some reason it has become slow to log into Cisco devices. How may I increase the speed for this script?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

log_user 0
set timeout 10
set userid  "id"
set password  "pass"

# ############## Get two arguments - (1) Device (2) Command to be executed
set device  [lindex $argv 0]
set command [lindex $argv 1]

spawn /usr/bin/ssh -l $userid $device

match_max [expr 32 * 1024]

expect {
    -re "RSA key fingerprint" {send "yes\r"}
    timeout {puts "Host is known"}
}

expect {
    -re "username: " {send "$userid\r"}
    -re "(P|p)assword: " {send "$password\r"}
    -re "Warning:" {send "$password\r"}
    -re "Connection refused" {puts "Host error -> $expect_out(buffer)";exit}
    -re "Connection closed"  {puts "Host error -> $expect_out(buffer)";exit}
    -re "no address.*" {puts "Host error -> $expect_out(buffer)";exit}
    timeout {puts "Timeout error. Is device down or unreachable?? ssh_expect";exit}
}

expect {
   -re "\[#>]$" {send "term len 0\r"}
  timeout {puts "Error reading prompt -> $expect_out(buffer)";exit}
}

expect {
   -re "\[#>]$" {send "$command\r"}
   timeout {puts "Error reading prompt -> $expect_out(buffer)";exit}
}

expect -re "\[#>]$"

set output $expect_out(buffer)
send "exit\r"
puts "$output\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `exp_internal 1` to your Expect script. You'll be able to see how Expect is matching the patterns. I suspect that your script happens to be pausing for $timeout seconds because one of your patterns failed to match.

Comment: you are absolutely right. here is the line pause and cause time out.send: sending "exit\r" to { exp6 }
write() failed to write anything - will sleep(1) and retry...
I don't know what's the problem with exit.

Comment: after you `send "exit\r"` you might want to `expect eof`

Comment: thanks for your response.expect eof help to exit properly now is some other line has issue - expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "exit\r\nConnection to router-A closed.\r\r\n"
write() failed to write anything - will sleep(1) and retry...
write() failed to write anything - will sleep(1) and retry...                                                             I really don't know what's try to write and failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first make sure the servers or devices hosting the SSH daemon are not running low on entropy, and I'd use [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) or similar to analyze the traffic to see which side of the connection seems to be waiting for the other.